# does int(11) and int(6) cause index issue?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL. So I found someone wrote some SQL in our production environment:

```
SELECT o.`erp_orders_id`
FROM `erp_orders` o
WHERE o.`orders_status`> 2
  AND o.`orders_status`< 5
  AND o.`shipmentAutoMatched` IN
    (SELECT s.`shipmentID`
     FROM `erp_shipment` s
     WHERE s.`shipmentScanLocal` = 2)
```

where `s.shipmentID` is `int(11)` while `o.shipmentAutoMatched` is `int(6)`.
This query hits an index

```
IDX_OR_OR_CU(orders_status, orders_type, currency_type)
```

While I actually have another index:

```
IDX_OR_SH(orders_status, shipmentAutoMatched)
```

which I think could be more efficient. and if I change the `IN` directive to numbers like:

```
IN(10, 11, 12)
```

the `IDX_OR_SH` is correctly hit. so I think the only problem might be about the `int(11)` and `int(6)`.

So the questions:

1. Am I correct?
2. How does this issue happen when `int(11)` and `int(6)` are both `int` and they are actually both stored as an `INT32`
3. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Before you start fiddling, ask yourself how much of a problem this is. If this query is run once a day, runs in 2 seconds and reports five rows, what difference is fiddling going to make? If the query is taking hours to run then maybe there's scope for optimisation, but I doubt that just changing that index will make a measurable difference.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I'm working on this issue because this SQL is frequently executed and slowed down the db instance a lot. This is actually from the slow SQL reported by the server.

Comment: maybe useful? [7 ways to convince MySQL to use the right index](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/7-ways-to-convince-mysql-to-use-the-right-index). Also: [8.8.3 EXPLAIN EXTENDED Output Format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-extended.html)

Comment: This is mostlikely a cardinality issue. Try flipping the columns i.e. `IDX_OR_SH_REVERSE(shipmentAutoMatched, orders_status)`.

Comment: @SalmanA Tried but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Phil I post an answer below. this has nothing to do with int(11) and int(6). it's a bug of MySQL innoDB.

Comment: @yaoxing I'll retract the vote

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who cares about the problem, this is probably [a bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9021) of InnoDB since 10 years ago. And it's supposed to get fixed in MySQL 6.0. Unfortunately I'm still using 5.5.

It has nothing to do with int(11) and int(6). Simply all subquery result won't hit parent query's index. Some people says change to `JOIN` statement would resolve this issue, but it doesn't seem to work for me though.

I will get back and update the answer when I get something new.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an index for the sub query but lose it after its been passed to the In

Rewrite this query as a join and you will see speed improvements. Especially on older versions of mysql ( newer versions have better performing sub queries. )

Mysql is pretty good at knowing which index to use. And if it decided one is a better index than the other. Mysql is usually correct. You can test with FORCE INDEX. make sure you use this on both smaller datasets and larger ones to get a true picture though

Comment: I tried but still the execution plan shows the SQL does not hit the `IDX_OR_SH`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

rewrite your query using jOIN

```
SELECT o.`erp_orders_id`
FROM `erp_orders` o
INNER JOIN `erp_shipment` s ON (s.`shipmentID` = o.`shipmentAutoMatched` AND s.`shipmentScanLocal` = 2)
WHERE o.`orders_status`> 2
  AND o.`orders_status`< 5
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me. the IDX_OR_SH is still not hit. Any idea?

Comment: have to agree, in My(SQL) experience using JOINs are much quicker and more efficient than sub-selects. Behind the scenes is a query plan builder that tries to make the most efficient use of indexes - splitting your SQL into sub-selects prevents this from optimising your query. Try adding `EXPLAIN` before your query to see how MySQL is using your indexes

Comment: oh, and try using `IN` or `BETWEEN` when checking values of order_staus. e.g. `o.order_status IN (3,4)` or `o.order_status BETWEEN 3 AND 4` so MySQL can actually use the index that is on this field (you can put your backticks in, they got lost in the edit)

Comment: even if I changed to order_status=4, the issue remains the same.

Comment: it seems that cardinality of your index by `order_status` is too low. put some data with random (just for test) values in `order_status`, then your index will work. seems like not working project? alpha yea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is with `int(11)` and `int(6)` The * in `INT(*)` has nothing to do with space requirements or any other performance issues, it's really just the ***display width***. Actually it will be more useful with the `UNSIGNED ZEROFILL` Option. For example

```
INT(6) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL
000001
000011
------
INT(6) 
     1
    11
```

So i guess the problem should be somewhere else

Comment: anything else I need to provide to trouble shooting the issue?